# Java returns "ScrollView can host only one direct child" when there's only one direct child

Tags: java, android, exception, scrollview

I have my own custom made `ScrollView` as a main `View` of my `layout`, which contains one single `FrameLayout` and every other `View` is put inside it. It looks like this (this is sm_layout.xml):

```
<com.effeleven.utils.CustomScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:clickable="true">

    <FrameLayout...>

</com.effeleven.utils.CustomScrollView>
```

I did not have this exception thrown when I used the default Android `ScrollView`. Now I need a custom one, because I need to handle the scroll events inside the `ScrollView` (I have a `mapFragment` and `ListView`, which I can't replace with anything, because I follow a design pattern). What can be causing the exception, since my `CustomScrollView` contains only one FrameLayout, just like the previous `ScrollView` did?

This is my `CustomScrollView` class:

```
public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView {

public CustomScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sm_layout, this, true);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    final int action = ev.getAction();
    switch (action)
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            super.onTouchEvent(ev);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            return false;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            super.onTouchEvent(ev);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            return false;

    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: post your `sm_layout.xml`

Comment: @DeKaNszn sm_layout.xml is the one I've posted above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read **[ScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)**

> A view group that allows the view hierarchy placed within it to be
>   scrolled. Scroll view may have only one direct child placed within it
>   .

**Cause**

```
layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sm_layout, this, true);
```

You have included more than one xml Attributes as **children of a ScrollView**. You are holding <kbd>sm_layout.xml</kbd> . You **should remove this from Class** .

Comment: That was indeed the cause of the problem. Thank you. Which answer do I accept now though? Both are basically the same and resolve the problem.

Comment: @G.Rann As your wish .Here i am for sharing,catching Knowledge .

Answer (score 3):

In your **CustomScrollView** you are including another layout using LayoutInflater which is causing you the problem. Try commenting the layout and see if it works.

Comment: Yes. This was the problem, since I am adding another layout this way. Thank you.

Comment: If it helps , Do not forget to upvote and accept answer

Comment: I did upvote, but I don't have enough reputation, so you can't see the upvote :)

Comment: try accepting it as answer :) by clicking on the tick(check) on the left side